# androidで言語コードの表示名を取得するには

Tags: android

iosで言うところの以下の動作をさせるにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

`NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: "ja")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Locale("ja").getDisplayLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
// 引数は省略できます new Locale("ja").getDisplayLanguage();
```

参考
http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage(java.util.Locale)